# How to read all of the files in a specific directory in google drive using python?

Tags: google-drive-api, pydrive

I'm trying to go through all of the files in a folder to read and analyze them in python. There are a large number of these files and I would like to iterate through each file in the folder without having to hardcode the file names in.

```
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'1fasSmc7insM4cQOoCik0vmEvYLN6Z5XZ' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py in _loadfile(filename)
    120     try:
--> 121         with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
    122             obj = json.load(fp)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'client_secrets.json'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidClientSecretsError                 Traceback (most recent call last)
10 frames
InvalidClientSecretsError: ('Error opening file', 'client_secrets.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidConfigError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pydrive/auth.py in LoadClientConfigFile(self, client_config_file)
    386       client_type, client_info = clientsecrets.loadfile(client_config_file)
    387     except clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError as error:
--> 388       raise InvalidConfigError('Invalid client secrets file %s' % error)
    389     if not client_type in (clientsecrets.TYPE_WEB,
    390                            clientsecrets.TYPE_INSTALLED):

InvalidConfigError: Invalid client secrets file ('Error opening file', 'client_secrets.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)
```

Comment: Is this python library useful for your situation? https://github.com/tanaikech/getfilelistpy

Answer (score 0):

To search in the root directory, you can use:

```
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
```

This gives you a list of all files in the root.

To have a list of all files in a sub-directory, you can replace 'root' with the folder id.

```
folder_id = '****'
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'folder_id' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a code that I am actively using.

```
folder_id = '********'
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'{}' in parents and trashed=false".format(folder_id)}).GetList()
```